# HTML images in zip folder

Tags: html

I have zip folder that has my 4 html pages, 1 css style sheet and 1 javascript file. I also have an image folder which stores all my images I use in the webpage. However, When I go to open the browser say for example "home.html" inside the zip folder the images are not appearing.

However, when I have the folder unzipped it works fine.

Why does zipping the folder cause images to go weird?

This is my image:

[folder here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40TTz.png)

Comment: You can't link to anything stored inside a zip file as it's compressed and not readable by a browser.

Comment: @j08691 If the received opens the folder will the images work?

Answer (score 0):

Zip file is not a folder. It's a file. It's not the same kind, it should be handled different way.